# Snapshots for npm-packages in nexus

Tags: npm, snapshot, nexus3

Is there a feature that supports SNAPSHOT releases for npm-packages in `nexus 3`?
My npm package is in package.json like this:

```
"myPackage": "1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
```

Currently I have re-deploy enabled and I'm overriding my SNAPSHOT.

But I don't think this is a recommended way to handle snapshots and now I run into checksum errors for same version when I run `npm install`:

> [error]npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
>   2018-06-29T06:30:28.0364505Z
>
> [error]npm ERR! sha512-LrLp9iDmk8CC34NoQj/cElE70LxL7xNzjAAooxIABnXXCki5hPaZ2DggSZrrnr2iYNUQFOoRuvln/y/JvqwAxA==
>
> integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-LrLp9iDmk8CC34NoQj/cElE70LxL7xNzjAAooxIABnXXCki5hPaZ2DggSZrrnr2iYNUQFOoRuvln/y/JvqwAxA== but got sha512-SecqJp7P5woQjJ4xzj6xjd8PqCEizm2Fr3gh6lQzYXEQtWi49Rsa0wR6inLQkF0rvF/JKN6wO4njkwDOyASd7w==. (363851 bytes)

Any recommendations how to handle npm packages as snapshots?

Comment: Respectfully don't think this question has anything to do with NXRM3.  NXRM is a gateway to how the client behaves.  If you find NXRM isn't behaving how NPM client acts, IMO that'd be a bug.

Comment: You're right my main question was how to handle snapshots with npm. I've found a solution that worked for me when using the npm pre-releases mechanism. I deploy the snapshots with a timestamp like this: `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.[timestamp]` and if I reference it in package.json like this `^1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` the package with the latest timestamp will be installed.

Answer (score 3):

After some time I came across a good way to handle this scenario. It is important to know, that you don't need to reference a version number in your `package.json`. You can also reference to a distribution tag like `latest` or `snapshot`.

You only have to take 2 steps to get the newest snapshot published in your repo.

1. Publish the snapshot packages under the tag `snapshot` in the NPM repository with this command: `npm publish --tag snapshot`.
2. Reference the `tag` instead of the `version` in the package.json of other projects as seen below.

package.json:

```
"myPackage": "snapshot"
```

Now everytime you call `npm install` the version you published latest will be installed.

Here is a screenshot of a npm repo that holds my latest snapshot (Nexus). As you can see, a npm install for my package.json will resolve the `tag` snapshot to the version `11.2.0-SNAPSHOT.20181205001757` :

[image: npm repo snapshot tag]